# VBA - Extract data from mutliple files inside a folder and import to a single file

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA but i would like to tap on excel vba to enhance my work efficiency. Hence, i'm here to garner the helps from all the kind souls here. 
The problem is as follow:

I have mutliple excel files in a network folder. The files share a similarity in the name covention but not the entire file name. Eg. a b c d e v19_01Nov2012, a b c d e v19_02Nov2012, a b c d e v19_05Nov2012 and etc. 
These files have various worksheet, namely sheetA, sheetB and etc.

Next, i have a file "Nov2012.xlxs" that consolidate all the informations extracted from the above mentioned files located in a network folder. 
This file have various worksheet, namely sheetA, sheetB and etc.

What i want to do:
I need to open each and every excel file in the network folder and extracts data in cell "B17" from worksheet "sheetA" to the Nov2012.xlxs worksheet "sheetA" cell "B2".

Something to note: the content in column A of the Nov2012.xlxs consist of all the date of Nov (eg. 01Nov2012, 02Nov2012 , 03Nov2012 and etc). When a b c d e v19_01Nov2012 is opened, then the data in cell "B17" from worksheet "sheetA" should be copied into Nov2012.xlxs row that contains "01Nov2012" from worksheet "sheetA" and cell "B2".

Currently i am working on this code:

```
Sub FolderCrawler()
FileType = "*.xls*" 'The file type to search for
FilePath = "C:\Nov\" 'The folder to search

Dim OutputCol As Variant
Dim Curr_File As Variant
Dim FldrWkbk As Workbook

OutputCol = 1 'The first row of the active sheet to start writing to
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, OutputCol), Cells(3, OutputCol)) = FilePath & FileType

OutputCol = OutputCol + 1

Curr_File = Dir(FilePath & FileType)

Do Until Curr_File = ""
Set FldrWkbk = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & Curr_File, False, True) 'Open new data file
Sheets("sheetA").Range("B17").Copy 'Copy data from specific Range

'Move back to Master file
Workbooks("01Nov2012.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("sheetA").Cells(4, OutputCol).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

OutputCol = OutputCol + 1
FldrWkbk.Close SaveChanges:=False 'Close the data file

Curr_File = Dir 'Select Next File
Loop
Set FldrWkbk = Nothing
End Sub
```

Currently, I am encountering "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". Any idea why the problem is occuring?

Comment: Which line flags up when you step through the code using F8?

Comment: Sheets("sheetA").Range("B17").Copy 'Copy data from specific Range
This is the line that got flagged out.

Comment: My first thoughts would be that "sheetA" doesn't exist in the workbook FldrWkbk. My next thoughts would be if you need to activate sheetA before copying from it

Comment: I am sure "sheetA" is in the workbook FldrWkbk.

I have tried adding "Worksheets("SsheetA").Activate" but the code just die on me at the "Set FldrWkbk = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & Curr_File, False, True)"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are losing your reference to the correct workbook when you switch between files. You probably need to refer to the workbook and not just the worksheet: `FldrWkbk.Sheets("sheetA").Range("B17").Copy`

That being said, is there a reason you need to copy/paste? I would avoid that if possible. Set a reference to the master file:

```
Dim masterBook As Workbook
Set masterBook = ThisWorkbook
```

Then, after you set your FldrWkbk, assign the value from the file in question back to the master file:

```
masterBook.Sheets("sheetA").Cells(4, OutputCol).Value = FldrWkbk.Sheets("sheetA").Range("B17").Value
```

This also avoids using the `.Select` and `.Activate` commands that cause many issues.